# how do I calculate vehicle speed accurately? using a video

Tags: image-processing, video, deep-learning, computer-vision, video-processing

I estimate the speed of the object by tracking them over the frames using a deep learning-based tracking algorithm. I use the following formula to calculate the speed:

v= distance/time-passed

I tested the system against a recorded video (30FPS). Since I am using a non-GPU computer, my computer can only process the video with the speed of 2 FPS, so due to this matter, it introduces a lag to the speed estimation system, as a result, the speed estimation will not be accurate. Due to that lag, the time passed becomes high, as a result, speed becomes low.
How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the distance from your tracking, but calculate the time of each frame using:

```
t = frame number / video frame rate
```

Comment: How do you mean exactly? I use a timer to calculate the time that it took to travel through that refrence lines.

Comment: Your timer measures how long it took you to process the frames, but you actually need to measure how long it took the tracked object to move from one reference line to the next. You measure that by saying the frames were recorded at, say, 30 frames per second therefore 33ms must have passed between consecutive frames.

Comment: I see, so how do I count the frames in that particular interval? is that really possible? I only saw examples of counting the entire video frames.

Comment: Each time you do a read from the video you get a frame, so just start a counter from zero and increment it each time you read a frame.